# Conversion for multiqual

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert the following input XML based on grouping of qualifier but its not working and not giving me expected output.

Below is the Input XML which has to be comverted.

```
<document>
<item>
    <gtin>1000909090</gtin>
    <attrGroupMany name="foodAndBevPreparationInfo">
        <row>
            <attr name="preparationType">BOILING</attr>
            <attrQualMany name="preparationInstructions">
                <value qual="en">Prep 8</value>
                <value qual="en">Prep 9</value>
                <value qual="ar">Test</value>
            </attrQualMany>
        </row>
    </attrGroupMany>
</item>
</document>
```

The XSLT which I am using but not giving me expected output.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="prepmvl" match="preparationInstructions" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @qual)" />  

<xsl:template match="document"> 
    <CatalogItem>
 <RelationshipData>
        <xsl:for-each select="item/attrGroupMany[@name ='foodAndBevPreparationInfo']/row">
            <Relationship>
                    <RelationType>Item_Master_Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL</RelationType>                  
                <RelatedItems count="{count(attrQualMany[@name='preparationInstructions']/value[generate-id() = generate-id(key('prepmvl', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @qual))[1])])}">                        
                <xsl:apply-templates select="attrQualMany[@name='preparationInstructions']/value[generate-id() = generate-id(key('prepmvl', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @qual))[1])]"/> 
                </RelatedItems>
            </Relationship>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>

</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="preparationInstructions">              
    <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="{concat('Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL','-',ancestor::item/gtin,'-',attr[@name='preparationType'],'-',@qual)}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the expected output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CatalogItem>
<RelationshipData>
    <Relationship>
        <RelationType>Item_Master_Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL</RelationType>
        <RelatedItems count="2">
            <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL-1000909090-BOILING-en" />
            <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL-1000909090-BOILING-ar" />             
        </RelatedItems>
    </Relationship>
</RelationshipData>
</CatalogItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

```
<xsl:key name="prepmvl" match="preparationInstructions" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @qual)" />
```

to

```
<xsl:key name="prepmvl" match="value" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @qual)" />
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="preparationInstructions">              
    <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="{concat('Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL','-',ancestor::item/gtin,'-',attr[@name='preparationType'],'-',@qual)}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="value">              
    <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="{concat('Food_And_Bev_Prep_MVL','-',ancestor::item/gtin,'-',../preceding-sibling::attr[@name='preparationType'],'-',@qual)}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you have found this answer useful. Kindly tick on the check mark on the left (to make it appear green). This way other users can know that this is the accepted answer. Kindly do this also in all of your questions. Though, you can only accept 1 answer per question.